# Multiple file attachments in email

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code to send an email with attachments.  I can send one attachment but how can I send multiple attachments?

```
Dim vrAttachFilePath As String = "c:\users\ittahad\documents\abc.doc"
If vrAttachFilePath.Length > 0 Then
    oMail.Attachments.Add(New Net.Mail.Attachment(vrAttachFilePath))
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put quite simply:

```
Dim vrAttachFilePathFile1 As String = "c:\users\ittahad\documents\abc.doc"
Dim vrAttachFilePathFile1 As String = "c:\users\ittahad\documents\def.doc"

oMail.Attachments.Add(New Net.Mail.Attachment(vrAttachFilePathFile1))
oMail.Attachments.Add(New Net.Mail.Attachment(vrAttachFilePathFile2))
```

You can add as many attachments as you want simply by calling `Attachments.Add` with each attachment.

Answer (score 3):

You could add multiple elements to the Attachments collection:

```
oMail.Attachments.Add(New Net.Mail.Attachment(path1))
oMail.Attachments.Add(New Net.Mail.Attachment(path2))
oMail.Attachments.Add(New Net.Mail.Attachment(path3))
...
```